# Counting commas in text(multithreading), am I doing it right?

Tags: java, multithreading, performance

I'm counting the commas in a text using 5 threads by splitting the text in 5 equal parts and letting each thread work on it's own portion. I'm just wondering if I am doing it right:

```
public class CommaCounter implements Runnable {

    public static int commaCount = 0; // it's static so that all CommaCounter threads share the same variable

    private String text;
    private int startIndex;
    private int endIndex;

    public CommaCounter(String text, int startIndex, int endIndex) {
        this.text = text;
        this.startIndex = startIndex;
        this.endIndex = endIndex; 
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {

        for (int i = startIndex; i < endIndex; i++) {
            if(text.charAt(i) == ','){
                commaCount++; // is incrementing OKAY? is there danger of thread interference or memory consistency errors?
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And the main method:

```
public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws MalformedURLException, IOException, InterruptedException {

        long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        /*
            I'll spare the code that was here for retrieving the text from a URL
        */

        String text = stringBuilder.toString();

        Set<Thread> threadCollection = new HashSet<>();

        int threadCount = 5;
        int textPerThread = text.length() / threadCount;
        for (int i = 0; i < threadCount; i++) {
            int start = i * textPerThread;
            Thread t = new Thread(new CommaCounter(text, start, start + textPerThread));
            threadCollection.add(t);
            t.start();
        }

        for (Thread thread : threadCollection) {
            thread.join(); // joining each CommaCounter thread, so that the code after the for loop doesn't execute prematurely
        }

        long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        System.out.println("Counting the commas with " + threadCount + " threads took: " + (endTime - startTime) + "ms");
        System.out.println("Comma count: " + CommaCounter.commaCount);
    }

}
```

Mainly I'm worried if incrementing commaCount is done properly, i.e. is there any danger of thread interference or memory consistency errors. Also I'm currious why the execution time wasn't way better than it was when counting the commas with a single thread(it was pretty much the same).

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: This is not work,  I would suggest you to implement java.util.concurrent.Callable in the class of CommaCounter  which you can get the result after thread finish

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Absolutely not ok. You're accessing a static variable from multiple threads. Use an AtomicInteger or a synchronized static method.

As stated in your comment, exactly :)

Either make it an AtomicInteger and use the getAndIncrement or incrementAndGet method,

or create a static synchronized method,

or create a synchronized block, but in this case, make sure that the object on which you synchronize is the same! As this is about the static variable in class CommaCounter, that could be CommaCounter.class

Comment: Aha, got it. So basically I have 3 options: 1) Make the static variable commaCounter an AtomicInteger; 2) Put the commaCounter++ statement in the run() method in a synchronized block; and 3) Make a designated synchronized method just for incrementation

Comment: Right? And also, is there any problem having static fields(like commaCounter) in Runnable objects as long as everything is synchronized?

Comment: A static field is just a global variable. It does not matter at all in which context it is declared. It also does not matter on which object you synchronize, as long as all threads accessing the same variable are synchronizing on the same object!

Comment: synchronized without an explicit object means synchronized(SurroundingClass.class) for static methods, and synchronized(this) for non-static methods.

Comment: I jus want to add 2 points. 1- your method will work only if the number of char is a multiple of threadCount otherwise you will louse the last chars. 2-i think you dont's see the exec time difference because if your string is not long enough threads instantiation and mechanism take more time than you gain... try with very big strings

Comment: @Med-SalahOKA Thanks for the feedback! It came to my mind as well that there could be a problem with the last few chars if the number of chars is not a multiple of the thread count. Do you have any quick suggestions on how to tackle that?

Comment: hint: (length + numthreads - 1) / numthreads is the same as x / numthreads, x being length iff length is divisble by numthreads, else the next integer that is divisible by numthreads.

Comment: sometimes people suggest using double and Math.ceiling but that is a very bad habit because doubles only have 53 bits of precision, and I think float has 27, so you introduce rounding errors for bigger numbers. avoidable rounding errors in a purely integer problem are really sad (this is also one of the worst things about javascript and lua -.-)

Comment: This is missing the most performant solution you'd see most likely in reality: Have thread local counts and only do a single atomic increment per thread or just sum up after all threads are joined. This minimized the synchronization overhead you'd otherwise have.

Comment: So you are suggesting map / reduce with the AtomicInteger as the device for reducing all results to the common result :D

Comment: As much as I love using map / reduce for real world tasks, I think this question is about understanding the very fundamentals of synchronizing single increments in between several threads 

Answer (score 1):

I guess this problem exactly match fork and join framework

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/forkjoin.html

Since it uses parallel divide and conquer technique, it will keep splitting your text and assign the work to new thread, also using "working stealth" technique to ensure that all threads are busy.

Comment: That's a great suggestion for step seven or so, right after understanding the fundamentals of synchronizing access to variables, followed immediately by understanding volatile Java fields, atomic primitives, and java.util.Concurrent, so you even have a chance to grasp what's going on inside a high-level framework like fork / join 